# How do I access "this" with a nested class, in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Consider this example.

```
public class myclass {

public void...
public int ...

    private class my_nested_class {
          Intent i = new Intent(this, List.class);
    }

}
```

I would like "this" to be myclass.  How can I do that? "this.super"? But that doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you wanto to tag it also with android?

Comment: Every nested class has its own 'this'.  What you mean is `how do I access the enclosing outer class instance' and its answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `myclass.this`.

By the way, class names start with a capital letter in Java, you should rename your class MyClass.