# How can i access OuterClass through inner class instance?

Tags: java, class, nested

I know i can get the instance of the enclosing class using:

```
OuterClass.this
```

But i can do it only within the inner class code itself. only I have is **reference** of the Inner class instance **withing another class code.** How can i get the OuterClass instance through the inner class instance?

Comment: While it might be possible to actually do that (interesting question!), you should probably reconsider your design (or post a reasonable example where such access is really needed)

Comment: Here is a good answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 3):

You can define a getter that returns `OuterClass` to callers from the outside:

```
public class InnerClass {
    ...
    public OuterClass getOuterInstance() {
        return OuterClass.this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (but you shouldn't) use reflection for the job:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create the inner instance
        Inner inner = new Outer().new Inner();

        // Get the implicit reference from the inner to the outer instance
        // ... make it accessible, as it has default visibility
        Field field = Inner.class.getDeclaredField("this$0");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        // Dereference and cast it
        Outer outer = (Outer) field.get(inner);
        System.out.println(outer);
    }
}
```

Of course, the name of the implicit reference is utterly unreliable, so as I said, you shouldn't :-)