# Java JFrame creating close button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've written a form and through looking through various resources have come up with a form that can close itself when "X" is pressed. However, I seem to have done it in a fairly hack-tastic way.

(The code I'm posting has been striped of the non-relevant cosmetic details, but it is in-essence a pop-up notification based on this tutorial: http://harryjoy.me/2011/07/01/create-new-message-notification-pop-up-in-java/)

```
public class Notification extends JFrame {

    private JFrame uglyJFrameHack;

    public Notification(String header, String message) {
        super();
        uglyJFrameHack = this;
        JButton closeBtn = new JButton("X");
        closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                uglyJFrameHack.dispose(); //here's where this all seems screwy.
            }
        });
        this.add(closeBtn);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to use "this" in the actionPerformed method without it referencing something else. I did a `System.out.println(this.getClass());` and it gave me `class Notification$1`. So I tried to type cast it to a Notification object, but eclipse give me an error stating `Cannot cast from new ActionListener(){} to Notification`.

The way I have it setup works and doesn't seem to have any issues, but this also doesn't seem like good practice. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write more generic code by accessing the source object of the event:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent((Component)e.getSource());  
window.dispose();
```

Now you can use this ActionListener in any GUI because you haven't hardcode the class name as part of the code.

Comment: So I came across this again, I remembered that I had asked this question before so I looked it back up. Going over these two answers I realize now that this should have actually been the chosen answer the first time around. Thanks for this

Comment: `I realize now that this should have actually been the chosen answer the first time around.` - thanks, better late than never ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Notification.this.dispose();
```

Just using `this` refers to the `ActionListener`.

---

Fairly similar to: [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Comment: Okay, after reading that it makes much more sense. Thanks for your help!