# Get Outer Class Variable From Inner Class (local variable)

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to figure out a way for the position variable from the `getView()` method to be passed to the inner class.  However this can't be a final variable because `getView()` gets called for each item in the `ListView` and hence it changes.  Is there a way to access that position variable without having it be final?  or making it final in a clever way that would make something like this work?  Here is my code

```
public class AlarmListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Alarm> {


    public AlarmListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Alarm> alarms) {
        super(context, resource, alarms);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = viewInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_alarm_list, null);
        }
        Alarm alarm = getItem(position);
        if (alarm != null) {
            TextView alarmName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_name);
            TextView alarmTime = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_time);
            Switch status = (Switch) view
                .findViewById(R.id.alarm_list_item_status);
            alarmName.setText(alarm.getName());
            alarmTime.setText(alarm.getFormattedHour() + ":"
                + alarm.getMinute() + " " + alarm.getAMPM());
            status.setChecked(alarm.getOn());
            status.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Alarm alarm = getItem(position);
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `position` variable final, it will be OK. You're using it as a read only variable.
Also making it final has no effect on the caller, only on the body of your method you won't be allowed to change it.