# Substitute for activity argument when calling a class from AsyncTask

Tags: android

here's a portion of my code:

```
public class Login  extends Activity {

private class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean returnResult) {
            DialogSelectAccount dsa=new DialogSelectAccount(getParent());
             dsa.show();

      }
   }
}

public class DialogSelectAccount extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener  {


    public DialogSelectAccount(Activity a) {
        super(a);
    }
}
```

but when I run the app, it get a NPE error at the "super(a)" under the public DialogSelectAccount();

but when I changed my code to

```
public class Login  extends Activity {

private class LoginUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean returnResult) {
            test();

      }
   }

public void test(){
        DialogSelectAccount dsa=new DialogSelectAccount(this);
        dsa.show();
    }
}
```

it works. So what if I don't want to create a separate method like above and calls DialogSelectAccount directly inside the onPostExecute, what should I pass as the argument?

Thanks

Comment: use `ActivityName.this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what if I don't want to create a separate method like above and calls DialogSelectAccount directly inside the onPostExecute, what should I pass as the argument?

answer:

```
DialogSelectAccount dsa=new DialogSelectAccount(Login.this);
```

This is rather general java question, for more on inner classes read here: [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Answer (score 0):

The dialog class needs a Context attribute. 
When you say getParent() - I suppose it does not return context.

You can keep the context attribute in a global class and retrieve it - though I will not recommend that.