# Resolving Ambiguity when Accessing Parent Class from Anonymous Class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I recently ran into something like this...

```
public final class Foo<T>
implements Iterable<T> {

    //...

    public void remove(T t) { /* banana banana banana */ }

    //...

    public Iterator<T> Iterator {
        return new Iterator<T>() {

            //...

            @Override
            public void remove(T t) {
                // here, 'this' references our anonymous class...
                // 'remove' references this method...
                // so how can we access Foo's remove method?           
            }

            //...

        };
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to while keeping this as an anonymous class? Or do we have to use an inner class or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access `remove` in the enclosing class, you can use

```
...
    @Override
    public void remove(T t) {
        Foo.this.remove(t);         
    }
...
```

Related question: [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Answer (score 2):

Foo.this.remove(t) will do the trick for you.

Comment: There are already exactly the same answers. Please upvote them instead of posting a duplicate one.