# Access outer class function from Object of Inner Class

Tags: java, nested, nested-class

I know there are similar question put up related to this issue, but however, I wasn't able to resolve my issue. I've tried to simplify my problem to the following code -

```
class Outer
{
    Outer()
    {}

    class Inner
    {
        Inner()
        {}
    }

    void func()
    {
        System.out.println("Outer");
    }
}

public class Nested
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Outer oo = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner ii = oo.new Inner();

//          ii.func(); I know this won't work


    }
}
```

Can I call outer class function "func()" from object of inner class "ii"..?? If yes, how?

Comment: You cannot do that, why would you think you could?

Comment: why do you want to call from inner class when you could clearly do it from outer?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: the reference to `Outer.this` is `private` in `Inner` so you cannot access the reference to the `Outer` instance from an instance of the `Inner`.

You can export this reference thus:

```
class Outer {
    Outer() {
    }

    class Inner {
        Inner() {
        }

        public Outer getOuter() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }

    void func() {
        System.out.println("Outer");
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
ii.getOuter().func();
```

Comment: Was just about to write exactly the same answer (even with the same method name)

Comment: @BoristheSpider seems like all great mind thinks same function name : Jon Skeet here same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Comment: @user3554962 rather than commenting with thank-yous, please consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use Outer.this.func() from the inner class.
Do note that you can only do this from the inner class, not from outside.

Comment: `Outer.this` is `private` in `Inner`. You cannot access it like that.

Comment: Lol thats exactly what I mean

Comment: Well then it's not very helpful to the use case of the OP is it? I.E. it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: It answers the question. Read the last line of the question carefully.

Comment: The OP wants to access the method `func` on `Outer` from an instance of `Inner` in _another class_ - `Nested`. This does not answer the question, it answers a different question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Read this quote: "Can I call outer class function "func()" from object of inner class "ii"..??" The answer is, as mentioned, no.

Comment: Yes, _from an object in inner class_. I have an `Inner ii`, how do I call `func()` using your method??

Comment: There is no way to do so without providing new methods in ii. That is EXACTLY what I tried to tell you.

Comment: Is it? I don't see any mention of "new" or "method" in your answer. You answer just says _Use `Outer.this.func()` from the inner class._ I still insist that this answer doesn't even come close to answering the question. Maybe the comments clarify things a little, but the answer it still useless.

Comment: If you are not happy with my answer, feel free to EDIT it.

Comment: Also, read it again, what would you do if I say that you can only use the scope from the inner class?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Outer {
   Outer() {}
   class Inner {
     Inner() {}

     void callFunc() {
       Outer.this.func();
     }
  }

  void func() {
     System.out.println("Nested");
  }
}

public class Nested {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   Outer.Inner ii = new Outer().new Inner();
   ii.callFunc();

 // ii.func(); I know this won't work
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
package com;


class Outer
{
    Outer()
    {}

    class Inner
    {
        Inner()
        {}
        public Outer g(){
            return Outer.this;}
    }

    void func()
    {
        System.out.println("Outer");
    }
}

public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Outer oo = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner ii = oo.new Inner();


         ii.g().func(); 


    }
}
```