# Get refecence ton contining instance from anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have the following code:

```
class Foo 
{
    public Foo()
    {
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
            {
                // how can I use a reference to Foo here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use member variables of the current `Foo` instance from inside `actionPerformed`. I I use `this` I get the instance of `ActionListener`. But how can I get a reference to the current `Foo` instance itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the Foo instance by using `Foo.this`:

```
class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
      {
        Foo thisFoo = Foo.this;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

with `Classname.this` you get the instance in your `ActionListener`:

```
class Foo 
{
  void doSomething(){
      System.out.println("do something");
  };

    public Foo()
    {
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
            {
                Foo.this.doSomething();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local variable containing "this" and use it in the Anonymous inner class:

```
final Foo thisFoo = this;
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        // use thisFoo in here
    }
};
```