# accessing outer class variables via an inner class reference

Tags: java, inheritance

```
 public static class Outer {
        public int field;
        public class Inner {}
 }


 //  caller methods
 public static void foo(Outer.Inner inner) {
       // here I want to access the "field"
       // tried the following, none worked
       System.out.println(inner.Outer.field);
       System.out.println(inner.Outer.this.field);
 }
```

How do I access a non-static fields of a class from a reference of its non-static inner class in Java?

**P.S**
People kept saying it's bad design. Yes, I agree 100% this is bad "design". At least, it's bad for code that needs to be read by humans. But if this is for generated code, I think I'll get a pass. (have anyone tried reading code that comes out of Antlr, for eg?)

Comment: Not a Java expert but that seems like an invalid thing to do. Why do you want to do this anyways, kind of sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Nope you cant do that. You would have to add either getters to Outer or Inner

Comment: This seems incredibly wrong.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Look, I agree 100% this is bad "design". At least, it's bad for code that needs to be read by humans. But if this is for generated code, I think I'll get a pass. (have anyone tried reading code that comes out of Antlr, for eg?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a not-too-good idea, but anyway, you'll need to explicitly export it yourself.

```
public static class Outer {
    public int field;
    public class Inner {
        public Outer outer() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }
}

//  caller methods
public static void foo(Outer.Inner inner) {
   System.out.println(inner.outer().field);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work - bad coding practice anyway

```
 public static class Outer {
        public int field;
        public class Inner {
            public Outer outer=Outer.this
        }
 }


 //  caller methods
 public static void foo(Outer.Inner inner) {
       System.out.println(inner.Outer.field);
       System.out.println(inner.Outer.this.field);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, so essentially you expose a reference to the outer class. This feels like soemthing java should have made default! Thanks!

Comment: IMHO this is something you should rather avoid and redesign into simpler composition of classes.

Answer (score 0):

One option is mentioned in the other answers. If for some reason it doesn't fit your case, you can expose `field` from Inner, with getter (and setter if you need to):

```
public Outer class {
    private int field;
    public class Inner {
        public int getOuterField() {
            return field;
        }
    }
}
```

A different approach would to be pass the corresponding `Outer` instance wherever you need to use `Inner`, so `foo` will take two arguments in this case.

And yeah, I agree with all the comments posted - all of the options indicate bad design.