# instance variables not recognized with "this" w/in Runnable

Tags: java, runnable

I was having a bizarre time trying to reference instance variables of a class within a runnable. Here was my (simplified) code:

```
public class Hello{

    private Boolean truth;

    public Hello(Boolean truthParam){

        this.truth = true;

        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if (this.truth){
                    System.out.println("i declare the truth!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("come back tomorrow");
                }

            }
       };
    }
}
```

When I compiled this code, I got "error: cannot find symbol ... symbol: variable truth"

I thought perhaps within the context of the Runnable, "this" was no longer the main class object; however, I printed "this" to the console, and it was an instance of Hello. Which begs the question: why was I unable to access my instance variable via this?

I then removed the "this" from `if (this.truth)`, converting it to `if (truth)`; needless to say, this compiled and ran. I am quite confused by this behaviour I cannot explain. Perhaps I am simply misunderstanding the intricacies of "this"...

Comment: It's because, 'this' is the runnable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object#1816462

Comment: @matt while that is true the problem for the actual error message is that `truth` was simply never declared.

Comment: @Ben they claim that it is a simplified version, and that it compiled and worked without the 'this'. So yes this code the op has presented wouldn't compile, but their question is most likely based on the question I have linked to.

Comment: Yes, definitely true. I didn't see the (simplified). My bad.

Comment: Yep whoops in my simplification I accidentally declared the variable as truthParam rather than truth. sorry for the confusion

Comment: But @matt how do you explain the console log of this to the console produced an instance of Hello rather than of Runnable?

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente where did you put the 'this'. You either put it outside of the Runnable, and this referred to the class Hello. Or you put it inside of the Runnable, in which case it is an anonymous class inside of Hello, so when you print it out it will say `Hello$1@XXX`. That $1 (or $X where X is the number of anonymouse classes.) indicates it is an anonymous class inside of Hello.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:

You are assigning `this.truth = true`. However you never declared `this.truth`.

You need to make a field `private boolean truth` if you want to have it as a field of your class or use `final boolean truth = true` in your constructor if you just want it locally (although that would be mostly pointless).

---

Regarding the usage of the `this` keyword:

`this` always refers to the object the method you are callign is residing in.

In your line `if(this.truth) {` you are in the method `run` of an object of type `Runnable`. So `this` refers to this exact object of type `Runnable` which does not have a field of name `truth`. Therefore `this.truth` throws an error.

You can either simply use `truth` or use `Hello.this.truth`.

The second would be mostly useful if you have a field `truth` in your class yourself but want to access the field in the class `Hello`.

So, imagine a simple use-case:

```
public class A
{
    private boolean field = false;

    public void foo()
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            private boolean field = true;

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(field); // prints true
                System.out.println(this.field); // prints true
                System.out.println(A.this.field); // prints false
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Super thanks so much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

In your code, **this** refers to the object of the **Runnable** class.
What you actually want is the object for the **Hello** class.
If you're inside two classes, the **this** keyword will refer to the inner one.
One way to refer to the outer one is writing **Class.this**
In this case you need to change to (also a minor error in the name of the field)

```
public class Hello{

private Boolean truth;

public Hello(Boolean truthParam){

    this.truth = true;

    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            if (Hello.this.truth){
                System.out.println("i declare the truth!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("come back tomorrow");
            }

        }
   };
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a bunch I'd accept this but I can't accept 2 answers