# In Kotlin, why can't I access the outer class on an instance of an inner class?

Tags: kotlin

Why can't I access the outer class's properties on an instance of an inner class?

```
class A(val id: String) {

    inner class B {}
}

fun test() {
    val a = A("test")
    val b = a.B()
    aid(a)
    bid(b)
}

fun aid(a:A): String = a.id
fun bid(b:A.B): String = b.id //Unresolved reference: id
```

In this example, b.id fails to compile.

I gather that I have to add a getter on B that returns `this@A.id`. But why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An inner class just has a reference to the enclosing instance, and therefore does not inherit the outer class's members.

As inner classes have a reference to the enclosing class, this enclosing instance can be accessed *within the class only* (Java: `Outer.this`, Kotlin: `this@Outer`), but you are correct that you cannot access the enclosing instance from outside the inner class.

> A class may be marked as `inner` to be able to access members of outer class.
>   <sub>[Kotlin Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/) / [Nested and Inner Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html)</sub>

Making your own getter function to return the enclosing instance is [the only way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458) to do this.

Though the generated reference to the outer instance is package-private [according to Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816462/7366707), neither Java nor Kotlin has any method of obtaining this instance. You *can* use reflection, but as the generated field name is possibly unreliable, your best choice is to modify the inner class.