# Get outer object by inner in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to access name variable having a reference to object B without modifying B class?

```
class A {
    val name = "Name"
    
    inner class B {
        
    }
    
}

val b: A.B = ...
```

Maybe there is a way of getting reference to A object having variable b?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do this without modifying B
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088622/in-kotlin-why-cant-i-access-the-outer-class-on-an-instance-of-an-inner-class

Comment: @VitaliTsirkunov You have a contradiction between the title and the text of your post: "outer object" vs "reference to A class". "Outer object" = instance of A, "reference to A class" = the class A. First case: not possible as already mentioned by Steyrix. Second case: just us A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose the A reference from within B:

```
class A {
    inner class B {
        val a get() = this@A
    }
}
```

Now you can access a with `val a: A = someB.a`