# Accessing outer scope with qualified this in extension functions for inner classes

Tags: kotlin, syntax

How can I access outer scope from an inner class when I create an extension function for it?

Example

```
class A {
    inner class B {
        fun own() = this@A
    }
}
```

This code compiles and executes as it is supposed to.

When I add the following extension function

```
fun A.B.ext() = this@A
```

The compilation fails with

```
Error:(7, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: @A
```

I read the documentation for [qualified this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) and it briefly mentions extension functions, but without any example.

Is it possible to access outer scope from extension functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension function can only do things a non-extension `fun ext(x: A.B)` can do, so I would expect not, just like [you can't access it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object). This is because it compiles to such a function, the syntax just makes it look like a member.

While class `B` has a field containing a reference to the outer `A` instance, this field can't be accessed directly from code by name. Allowing access to it would [violate encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object#comment1706317_1816462).

The linked page talks about "access[ing] `this` from an outer scope". "Scope" here is used in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science), so in the example you have scopes where the comments say "implicit label"

```
class A { // outer scope 1
    inner class B { // outer scope 2
        fun Int.foo() { // function scope
        }
    }
}
```

while

```
fun A.B.ext() = ...
```

doesn't have any outer scopes (except for file scope, which doesn't have `this`). Unless it's really

```
class C {
    fun A.B.ext() = // can use this@C
}
```

but you can't write `this@A` or for that matter `this@B` because the function isn't defined in the scope of `class A` or `class B`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what confuses me is that the `own` member function of `B` successfully accesses the outer scope (e.g. in java terms it is `A.this`), but the `ext` extension function is unable to access it. From my perspective they should be the same since the bytecode for the inner (not static) class should have a reference to its outer class. Correct me if I am wrong, I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, it has a reference to the outer class. But it's a package-level field (not sure why it isn't private) which can be accessed from class methods, but can't be accessed from methods which just take it as an argument. It doesn't matter whether the methods are extension functions.

Comment: Second: the outer scope is not `A.this`, it's `class A { ... }`. Because `A.B.ext()` is not defined inside `class A`, that's not its outer scope. Again, in the documentations example outer scopes for `Int.foo()` are `class A { ... }` and `class B { ... }`, not `Int`.

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) for meaning of "scope".

Comment: But I define the extension function in the same package. Why can it not access the reference to the outer class?

Comment: That doesn't change anything about scoping, so it still isn't "`this` from outer scope". And the field is compiler-created and can't be accessed by name without reflection from Java or Kotlin (AFAIK).

Comment: And I agree with this comment there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object#comment1706317_1816462

Comment: Please update your answer with the additional information from the comments and I will accept your answer. It would be great if you briefly describe what internal mechanisms extensional functions use for them to work.

Comment: I figured out why the field isn't private (since it was surprising to me) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588276/why-is-this0-field-of-an-inner-class-not-private/54596734