# Determine if Object is a member of inner class?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I have the following code

```
public class A {
    public class B {
    }

    public boolean wasCreatedFromMe(B obj) {
       // I want to implement this method
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        B b1 = a1.new B();
        a1.wasCreatedFromMe(b1); // true
        a2.wasCreatedFromMe(b1); // false
    }
}
```

I would like to implement that method above which determines if the object was created from `this` Outer Class instance. Is there a way to use `instanceof` or some type of `Class<>` magic to do that?

I **do NOT** want to do any of the following:

Use data structures

```
// inside class A
Set<B> childObjs = new HashSet<>();

public B() {
    childObjs.add(this);
}
```

Ask inner class object

```
// inside class A
public boolean wasCreatedFromMe(B obj) {
    return obj.parent() == this;
}

class B {
    public A parent() {
        return A.this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection API can help you here.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Is there no other way, ex. through `instanceof` ?

Comment: Not much of a duplicate. No actual answers to this question short of reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting hold of the outer class object from the inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object)

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265900/1527544

Comment: @Antoniossss The only useful answers there are the reflective ones, and they don't fully answer this question. This has already been closed as a duplicate of that, and reopened.

Comment: And that particular answer is linked. Having method of extracting enclosing class instance breaks down this question to simple `==`comparision of instances which is not even worth mentioning.

Comment: It absolutely is a duplicate of the linked questions. The reason the answers there don't fulfil your conditions is that it's just not possible to fulfil them. You saying "but I wanna" doesn't change that fact, nor does it make the question less of a duplicate.

Comment: @daniu Perhaps you could suggest which of the three routes you would take then if you absolutely had to have this functionality? Would you do reflection (despite that user saying *"You could (but you shouldn't) use reflection for the job"*), sub-class method, or use a `Set`?

Comment: Definitely sub-class method, ie `class Inner { boolean createdFrom(Outer o) { return Outer.this == a); }}`. You can then also call this from `Outer` by `boolean createdByMe(Inner inner) { return inner.createdFrom(this); }` which is exactly the spec you were going for.