# how can I return the inverse Interface of an functional Interface using default method

Tags: java, functional-interface

I want to return an "Relation" using the default method "negate()", which always returns the opposite of the method test(). How can I do that?

```
public interface Relation<X,Y> {

    boolean test(X x, Y y);

    default Relation<X,Y> negate() {
        // TODO
        Relation<X, Y> relation = new Relation<X, Y>() {

            public boolean test(X x, Y y) {
                return !this.test(x, y);
            }
            
        };
        return relation;
    }
}
```

I tried this code however it gives me stack overflow error

Comment: In `return !this.test(x, y);`, the `this.test` is the default method that you are defining, so it is an infinite recursion.

Comment: `default Relation<X, Y> negate() { return (x, y) -> !this.test(x, y); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Relation` in its current form is a functional interface, we can return a lambda from `negate()` that inverts the result of `test(...)`:

```
public interface Relation<X, Y> {
    ...

    default Relation<X, Y> negate() {
        return (x, y) -> !this.test(x, y);
    }
    ...
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5Vev2v)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way doing this without using lamda expression?

Comment: You can always transform a lambda into an anonymous class: [`return new Relation<X, Y>() { public boolean test(X x, Y y) { return !Relation.this.test(x, y); } };`](https://ideone.com/uDMV6g)

Comment: Thank you very much, but the part "Relation.this.test(x, y)" confuses me, why do I need to write "Relation" before this?

Comment: Is that somehow because I am in a inner class and I want to access the method of the outer class?

Comment: Yes. See [this post and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816458/getting-hold-of-the-outer-class-object-from-the-inner-class-object).