# Access instance of outer class from mixin to inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, mixins, spongeapi

I'm targeting a non-static nested class, e.g.

```
package whatever;
class Outer {
    public int x;
    class Inner {
        public void foo();
    }
}
```

And I would like to write a SpongePowered Mixin for the inner class that refers to a field of the outer class, e.g.

```
@Mixin(targets = "whatever.Outer$Inner")
class InnerMixin {
    @Overwrite
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(Outer.this.x); //This doesn't work
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this work for normal, non-inner classes? Does this @Mixin already exist, or is it something you'd like to exist?

Comment: Are you talking about [SpongePowered Mixin](https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin)s? If yes, please edit that into the question.

Comment: Yes, I am, edited.  I couldn't find a tag for SpongePowered specifically, let me know if I missed one.

Answer (score 1):

The inner class has a synthetic (final) field, often but not always called `this$0`, which contains the instance of the outer class.  This field can be obtained by reflection as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265900) answer, or with a mixin it can be shadowed:

```
@Mixin(targets = "whatever.Outer$Inner")
class InnerMixin {
    @Shadow @Final Outer this$0;

    @Overwrite
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(this$0.x);
    }
}
```